# How can i remove empty string from array inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to remove the empty string from the array inside another array and I need to return the whole array without an empty string, can anyone help me with this, array is below

```
const testArr =  [
        {
            code: 'size',
            name: 'Size',
            options: ['small', "", "", "large"],
          
        },
        {
            code: 'color',
            name: 'COlor',
            options: ['black', "", "", "red"],
          
        },
    ]
```

I need result like this`(without empty string)`

```
[
    {
        code: 'size',
        name: 'Size',
        options: ['small', "large"],

    },
    {
        code: 'color',
        name: 'COlor',
        options: ['black', "red"],

    },
]
```

Comment: use `.filter()` method to filter out the empty strings: `array.filter(s => s.trim().length > 0)`

Comment: but `.filter()` is returning only options, I need a whole array without empty string @Yousaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map()` method to iterate over `testArr` and transform its elements and use `.filter()` method on the `options` array in each object, to filter out the empty strings.

```js
const testArr = [
  { code: 'size', name: 'Size', options: ['small', "", "", "large"] },
  { code: 'color', name: 'COlor', options: ['black', "", "", "red"] }
];

const result = testArr.map(obj => {
  obj.options = obj.options.filter(s => s.trim().length > 0);
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```